# Laravel shows blank page on localhost

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-artisan

I have a website in HTML, Javascript and PHP and now I'm trying to move it on Laravel framework. I've started with it a few days ago but I'm unable to load any pages. 
I tried php artisan optimize but that started giving me 404 error on everything so I'm starting from scratch.

I'm trying to load a simple Homepage.

This is my `routes>web.php`

```
<?php

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('/adminHome', function(){
    return view('/forms/adminHome');
});

Route::resource('forms','FormController');
```

This is my `views>forms>adminHome.blade.php`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Homepage</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ URL::asset('css/portfolio.css') }}" type="text/css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rajdhani|Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="page">
            <div id="header">
                <nav>                    
                    <ul>
                        <li><img class="logo" src="{{url('/images/logo.png')}}"></li>
                         <li><a href="adminHome.html">HOME</a></li>

                        <li><a href="login.html">LOG IN</a></li>
                        <li><a href="createAccount.html">SIGN UP</a></li>
                        <li></li>
                    </ul>
                    <footer>&copy; DiazApps ALL RIGHTS RESERVED BY <span class='nameColor'>ABCD WXYZ</span></footer>
                </nav>
            </div>
            <div id="pageContent">

                <div id="nameText">
                    <p class=titleText>HELLO I'M</p>
                    <p class=titleName>ABCD WXYZ</p>
                    <p class=titleText>DEVELOPER|</p>
                    <button onclick="window.open('/files/Resume.pdf')">Download My CV<i class="fa fa-download"></i></button>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I run php artisan serve and go to `http://localhost:8000/forms/adminHome` it shows me a blank page.
I've tried restarting the server several time but it doesn't work.

Output of php artisan route:list is

```
+--------+-----------+-------------------+---------------+---------------------------------------------+--------------+
| Domain | Method    | URI               | Name          | Action                                      | Middleware   |
+--------+-----------+-------------------+---------------+---------------------------------------------+--------------+
|        | GET|HEAD  | /                 |               | Closure                                     | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | adminHome         |               | Closure                                     | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | api/user          |               | Closure                                     | api,auth:api |
|        | GET|HEAD  | forms             | forms.index   | App\Http\Controllers\FormController@index   | web          |
|        | POST      | forms             | forms.store   | App\Http\Controllers\FormController@store   | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | forms/create      | forms.create  | App\Http\Controllers\FormController@create  | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | forms/{form}      | forms.show    | App\Http\Controllers\FormController@show    | web          |
|        | PUT|PATCH | forms/{form}      | forms.update  | App\Http\Controllers\FormController@update  | web          |
|        | DELETE    | forms/{form}      | forms.destroy | App\Http\Controllers\FormController@destroy | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | forms/{form}/edit | forms.edit    | App\Http\Controllers\FormController@edit    | web          |
+--------+-----------+-------------------+---------------+---------------------------------------------+--------------+
```

Because I'm only trying to display a page, I added any code to my controller.

Please tell me what am I doing wrong.

Comment: Check your apache/nginx server logs. If the page can't be displayed, there's likely an error of some kind, and if that error can't be logged to `storage/logs/laravel.log` (generally due to permissions), then it's logged to your server logs.

Comment: How did you create form Controller?

Comment: Could you please show Controller?

Comment: Try this..

Route::get('/adminHome', function(){
    return view('forms.adminHome');
});

Comment: I meant to say I haven't added any code to controller. Created it using php artisan make: controller FormController --resource

Answer (score 2):

Try this..

```
Route::get('/adminHome', function(){ 
    return view('forms.adminHome'); 
});
```

If forms is a application directory then url will be

> http://localhost:8000/forms/adminHome

or

> http://localhost:8000/forms/public/adminHome

Answer (score 0):

The URL for adminHome would be http://localhost:8000/adminHome in the case you have described. `/forms/adminHome` is a reference to where in the views folder that view lives.

Comment: Yeah I was trying to open it with http://localhost:8000/forms/adminHome and that's why it wasnt working

Answer (score 0):

I had to change it to

```
Route::get('/forms/adminHome', function(){
    return view('forms/adminHome');
});
```

for url to be  localhost:8000/forms/adminHome